# Login for hookups app

Tags: security, signup-signon

I'm developing an android app for hook ups with strangers, I understand that Facebook/Twitter login are not appropriate, but between security and flexibility, I'm confused how to register new users, I have the following options:

1. Google account login (Super easy for Android users, but maybe users do not want to link the ap to his account [thought: I can show message that says their profile will be separate from Google+ activities])
2. Phone Number (not as straightforward, and users might not want to, but will give me good identity confirmation)
3. Email (No security and not very good flow, but an option nonetheless)

Which one [or multiple] do I pick, this is an MVP and looking for a point to start from

Comment: How will phone number provide identity confirmation? I could say I'm brad pitt and give my own number, then confirm it just the same. At best I can prove that I'm the one that actually created the account but I think an email would serve just as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Require a phone number.** Think of your persona, Harry. (Taking some liberties here by making up your persona for you.) He is married, with two young children. He already has a girlfriend on the side, but she is getting demanding, so he wants to dump her, but not until he has identified a suitable replacement. He downloads your app and registers for the service, using his prepaid wireless phone that his partner knows nothing about. The same phone he has been using to arrange meet-ups with his current girlfriend via text.

My point is that people who value anonymity buy prepaid wireless phones to use in these types of scenarios. **Providing a phone number is a low bar to clear.**

As always, a focus on your users will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I would think creating a new email account would be a lower bar to clear than going out and buying a new phone. I could be wrong but I'd think the number of people willing to buy a burner phone (a somewhat smart phone too to use this Android app) just for this service would be small. EDIT: I suppose the phone doesn't have to be smart if he uses the app on one yet registers the burner

Comment: You're right, the phone would only be needed for the registration step, and I didn't suggest that Harry would be using mailinator for a disposable email address, but he probably would.